# What is the CSS selector for GtkSearchBar?

Tags: gtk, elementary-os

I've been trying to customize the Elementary GTK3 theme (I'm using elementary OS), and would like to have different padding each for `GtkEntry` and `GtkSearchBar`.

I set the padding for all `GtkEntry` type widgets using:

```
*.entry {
    padding: 4px 5px 4px 10px;
}
```

However, this seems to affect both the `GtkEntry` and `GtkSearchBar`.
[image]
[image]

The extra space before the search icon in `GtkSearchBar` could sure be done without. What I want is, the `GtkEntry` to have a `10px` padding to it's left as shown in the picture, and `4px` padding to the left of the `GtkSearchBar`.

How do I do this? I couldn't find a css selector (like `GtkComboBox.combobox-entry .entry`) meant specifically for a `GtkSearchBar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following CSS fragment. I added the `GtkSearchEntry` selector just in case, because the image you posted stinks of it.

```css
GtkEntry {
    padding: 4px 5px 4px 10px;
}
GtkSearchBar GtkEntry, GtkSearchEntry {
    padding: 4px 5px;
}
```

Comment: How did you find that?

Comment: @protoEvangelion I don't remember. I think now the appropriate way would be to use `entry` as selector instead, at least according to the CSS node section of [GtkEntry](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkEntry.html#id-1.3.10.2.11.7).